# Change the color of elements in Select from MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

It seems that there were quite a lot of questions and answers on this topic, but I could not find anything suitable for myself. I ask the community for help.

I'm using the Select component from `@mui/material` to display the number of records per page. And I'd like to change the color of the window's border when it's clicked, and the background color of the currently selected element.
I marked with a red arrow in the picture those elements that I want to change.

SelectMenuItemsPerPage.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItem, Select } from "@mui/material";
import { styles } from './SelectMenuItemsPerPageStyles';

export default function SelectMenuItemsPerPage({ pageSize, setPageSize }) {
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setPageSize(Number(event.target.value));
    };

    return (
        <Select
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={handleChange}
            sx={styles.Select}
        >
            <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>10</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={25}>25</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={50}>50</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={100}>100</MenuItem>
        </Select>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you add a sandbox?

Comment: Have u tried using a "Theme provider" ?
(if yes, then set the `theme.palette.primary.main` to a desired color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following CSS to this page, add this to index.css or globals.css (In the case of Next.js).

> The code

```
.MuiMenuItem-root.Mui-selected {
  background: yellow;
}
.MuiTablePagination-select[aria-expanded="true"] {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

> The output

[image]

Play around with the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-demo-material-ui-forked-x7u5zl?file=/public/demo.css)

Comment: this is not the same component

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MenuProps` and style it as follows:

```js
<Select
     MenuProps={{
        sx: {
          "&& .Mui-selected": {
            color: "red",
            background: "rgba(0,233,0,0.2)",
          },
        },
       }}
```

Here is the complete working example:

```js
<Select
      value={val}
      MenuProps={{
        sx: {
          "&& .Mui-selected": {
            color: "red",
            background: "rgba(0,233,0,0.2)",
          },
        },
      }}
      sx={{
        "& [aria-expanded=true]":{
          background: "rgba(0,233,0,0.2)",
        },
      }}
      onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
    >
      <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem selected value={10}>
        10
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={25}>25</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={50}>50</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={100}>100</MenuItem>
    </Select>
```

The output (You can style them as you wish):

[image]